# Are precooked frozen chicken wings bad for health?

Tags: diet, cholesterol

I am a student with limited time available to cook. I try to stay healthy, though, with eating rice pilaf (rice cooked with various vegetables), milk, nuts and fruits. I am immensely fond of chicken wings, available at Walmart. Do these pose any risk to health? I buy the "Nice" chicken wings sriracha glazed, which have 12% sodium.

I would be eating four wings at most in one day. My family has no history of hypertension.

Comment: 12 percent of what? Can't be 12 percent of the total, can it?

Comment: I assume you mean one serving provides 12% of the daily sodium intake according to guidelines.

Comment: If you really want to be healthy, remove the skin (I *know* -  it makes them less tasty). Also, consider stitching to switch to chicken breast for a better cut of meat. And rice doesn't do much for you - just lots of carbs & little in the way of nutritional value. You are doing well with the fruits & nuts, though.

Answer (score 2):

If you are worried about the sodium:

> WHO recommends a reduction to <2 g/day sodium (5 g/day salt) in adults (strong recommendation).

from the "Sodium intake for adults and children" guideline by the World Health Organisation. This is for healthy adults, sick people may need further restriction.

This means that ~15 grams of these wings would hit your daily sodium intake alone. Since you are probably consuming more than 2 g sodium daily even when you leave out the wings (2 g sodium is somewhat hard to get to even if you watch your intake), chances are that you need to cut out some intake source if you want to match the recommendation. The wings might be the easiest thing, as I doubt that any other food in your diet could reach 12% sodium.

If you are asking not about sodium, but for any potential health effect on you ever, which might occur from you changing your habits to not eat these wings? That's an unanswerable question.

Comment: "...which might occur from you changing your habits to not eat these wings?" Great line, and a very sound question nutritionally. +1